# How to transplant an index into a solr core

Tags: java, solr, lucene

My situation is this:

I have an index that has been generated by an entirely different app and I want to transplant/expose it from solr.

I can easily do that, but the problem now is I can't query on *any* of the fields. I just get empty {}

I modified the schema to include the fields from the documents transplanted and it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

When I do a `q=*:*` I can see all the documents so I know the info is there. This *has* to be easy. I am just missing it.

Would anyone like to give me an education?

Document example:

```
"docs": [
  {
    "code": "A000",
    "description": "Cholera due to Vibrio cholerae 01, biovar cholerae",
    "version": "10",
    "concepts": [
      "cholera",
      "cholera-due to biovar cholera",
      "cholera-due to vibrio cholerae 01",
      "infectious diseases",
      "intestinal infectious diseases"
    ],
    "tags": [
      "biovar",
      "cholera",
      "cholerae",
      "diseases",
      "infectious",
      "intestinal",
      "vibrio"
    ],
    "category": "A00",
    "etiology": "0"
  },
]
```

Comment: First start by using same schema as the one that generated the index. Second make sure version of Solr/lucene are same. Third, make sure your analyzers of the fields are same during query time. The \*:* works because it uses MatchAll query which skips everything. Start with doing simple code field query.

Comment: Will give all that a shot now. Thanks

Comment: Try to stick to what Arun says. If that does not work, I would ask you to give more details about how you create the index and how your core is configured, as we cannot know that.